# Cardview margin not showing correctly when using in listview

Tags: android, xml, android-cardview

I tried to create a list in my fragment, where I created a card view and using an adapter I populated the list with the card view. But the issue I am facing is, In my android studio XML layout, You can see a margin at both left and right of the screen, while when I installed on my phone, the margin is not seen!!

Android studio XML design:

[Android Studio XML Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdw4O.png)

[Whats comes when I installed on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x25K0.png)

My XML Code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/secndLaout"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/card_background_selector"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/rlImage"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_width="50dp">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageId"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:src="@drawable/mobeeloadicon"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlamount"

            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:paddingLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_height="20pt"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/rlImage"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/rlImage"
            android:layout_marginLeft="2pt">

            <TextView
                android:text="Paid To"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textSize="5pt" />

            <TextView
                android:text="xxxxx878"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/line2"
                android:layout_below="@+id/line1"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:textSize="7pt" />
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/descp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dateLayout"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dateLayout"
            android:layout_height="20pt">

            <!---->

            <TextView
                android:text="Credited to You"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/credit"
                android:textSize="5pt"
                android:layout_below="@+id/date"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="2dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="27/12/2017"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/date"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:textSize="5pt" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/line"
            style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:background="#e7e7e7"
            android:layout_below="@+id/descp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="6pt" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_below="@+id/line"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/head"
                android:layout_marginTop="3.5pt"
                android:layout_weight="3.0"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0">


                    <TextView
                        android:text="Amount Paid"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/amountinfo"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="6pt" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Cost"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/costinfo"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="6pt" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0">
                    <TextView
                        android:text="Balance"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/balanceinfo"
                        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textSize="6pt" />

                </RelativeLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/head"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/costLayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0">


                        <TextView
                            android:text="1200 RM"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/amount"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                            android:textSize="6pt"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1pt" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/amountinfolayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0">

                        <TextView
                            android:text="1000 RM"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/cost"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                            android:textSize="6pt"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1pt" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/balanceinfolayout"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1.0">
                        <TextView
                            android:text="80.5 RM"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:id="@+id/balance"
                            android:gravity="center_vertical"
                            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                            android:textAlignment="center"
                            android:textStyle="normal|bold"
                            android:textSize="6pt"
                            android:layout_marginTop="1pt" />

                    </RelativeLayout>

                </LinearLayout>
     </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

My Adapter Code :

```
public class CardArrayAdapter  extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
    private static final String TAG = "CardArrayAdapter";
    private List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<Card>();
    private Context mContext;

    static class CardViewHolder {
        TextView line1;
        TextView line2;
        ImageView cimageView;
        TextView amount;
        TextView credit;
        TextView date;

        TextView cost;
        TextView balance;
        TextView amountinfo;

        TextView costinfo;
        TextView balanceinfo;

    }

    public CardArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId);
        this.mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void add(Card object) {
        cardList.add(object);
        super.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.cardList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Card getItem(int index) {
        return this.cardList.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        CardViewHolder viewHolder;
        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_card, parent, false);
            viewHolder = new CardViewHolder();
            viewHolder.line1 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line1);
            viewHolder.line2 = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.line2);

            viewHolder.amount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amount);
            viewHolder.date = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.date);
            viewHolder.credit = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.credit);
            viewHolder.cimageView = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageId);


            viewHolder.cost = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.cost);
            viewHolder.balance = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.balance);
            viewHolder.amountinfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amountinfo);
            viewHolder.costinfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.costinfo);
            viewHolder.balanceinfo = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.balanceinfo);
            row.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (CardViewHolder)row.getTag();
        }
        Card card = getItem(position);

        viewHolder.line1.setText(card.getLine1());
        viewHolder.line1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.line2.setText(card.getLine2());
        viewHolder.line2.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

        viewHolder.amount.setText(card.getAmount());
        viewHolder.amount.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.date.setText(card.getDate());
        viewHolder.date.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#999999"));

        viewHolder.credit.setText(card.getCredit());
        viewHolder.credit.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.cost.setText(card.getCost());
        viewHolder.cost.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.balance.setText(card.getBalance());
        viewHolder.balance.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.amountinfo.setText(card.getAmountinfo());
        viewHolder.amountinfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.costinfo.setText("Cost");
        viewHolder.costinfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        viewHolder.balanceinfo.setText("Balance");
        viewHolder.balanceinfo.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

        Log.e("TRASACTION URL",Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE+card.getUrl());
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(Constants.BASE_URL_IMAGE+card.getUrl()).into(viewHolder.cimageView);
        return row;
    }

    public Bitmap decodeToBitmap(byte[] decodedByte) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
    }
}
```

What is wrong here! I could not find any possible reason here!

**--UPDATE--**

Finally i got this one correct.. Just adding a enclosing the cardview inside a Framelayout Solved the issue;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp">

    <!-- my layouts here -->

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView></FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 6):

use this attribute inside CardView widget tag in xml.

```
card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
```

IMHO, you should use this attribute and remove the

`android:layout_margin="10dp"`

from CardView tag.

Comment: This is the working answer!! Ty!

Answer (score 1):

put your cardview layout to frame layout, it works for me